# Reused while loop only working for one selection box

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I need to generate a list of teams from the cups selection box at the top of my page, this code allows me to run a while loop to generate the correct results for the first selection box, however, when i replicate the code in the second it shows no results?

```
      <form class="seed-form">
        <select name="team" required>
        <option value='Holder' disabled selected>Select Team</option> <!--Placeholder for Select-->
          <?php
          while ($team = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_teams)) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $team["team_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $team["team_name"]; ?></option>
          <?php } ?> <!--FILLS SELECT BOX WITH TEAMS FROM THAT CUP-->
        </select>
        <select name="team" required>
        <option value='Holder' disabled selected>Select Team</option> <!--Placeholder for Select-->
          <?php
          while ($team = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_teams)) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $team["team_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $team["team_name"]; ?></option>
          <?php } ?> <!--FILLS SELECT BOX WITH TEAMS FROM THAT CUP-->
        </select>



        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate" class="submit">
          <?php

          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //checking if submit button was clicked

            include_once 'action/dbcon.php';

            $cname = $_POST['cupname'];

            if (empty($cname)) {
                header("Location: tables.php?field=empty"); //return them if fields are empty
                exit();
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE cup_name='$cname'";
                $show_teams = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $numberCheck = mysqli_num_rows($show_teams);

                if ($numberCheck < 8) {
                header("Location: tables.php?tables=1"); //Take to cup page if there arent enough teams in the cup
                }
            }
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fetch_assoc()` returns the next row in the resultset, unless there are no more left (in which case it returns `NULL` - see [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)).

Your first `while` loop runs until there are no more results. Therefore when you start the second `while` loop, there are still...you guessed it: no more results. You already used them up. Therefore the first call to `fetch_assoc()` in the second loop returns `NULL` immediately, and so the loop condition is never met, and the loop never executes.

There are two different ways to solve this:

1) Reset the result pointer to the start of the resultset. Somewhere between the two loops, write

```
mysqli_data_seek($show_teams, 0);
```

See [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) for more info.

2) Read all the data into a PHP array, which you can then loop through as many times as you like using `foreach`:

```
      <?php
      $teams = array();
      while ($team = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_teams)) {
        $teams[] = $team;
      }
      ?>

      <form class="seed-form">
        <select name="team" required>
        <option value='Holder' disabled selected>Select Team</option> <!--Placeholder for Select-->
          <?php
          foreach ($teams as $team) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $team["team_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $team["team_name"]; ?></option>
          <?php } ?><!--FILLS SELECT BOX WITH TEAMS FROM THAT CUP-->
        </select>
        <select name="team" required>
        <option value='Holder' disabled selected>Select Team</option> <!--Placeholder for Select-->
          <?php
          foreach ($teams as $team) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $team["team_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $team["team_name"]; ?></option>
          <?php } ?> <!--FILLS SELECT BOX WITH TEAMS FROM THAT CUP-->
        </select>
```

Comment: Both methods are throwing Notice: Undefined variable: show_teams in C:\xampp\htdocs\friendlyfixtures\tables.php on line 96 and Warning: mysqli_data_seek() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\friendlyfixtures\tables.php on line 101

Comment: According to the code in your question, `$show_teams` is your query result object. So that's why I used that name. Maybe you changed it in the meantime or something?

Comment: none of the variable names were changed hence why im extremely confused, dont suppose you have any clue?

Comment: I can't see how you run the query and assign the result, so it's hard to be sure. Can you add that to the code in the question?

Comment: Not to worry, i placed the data seek elsewhere, now the variable is being recognised. However, i do also appreciate the array solution, thanks for the help!